# What is the difference between cmake, ccmake, make, and make install?

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, cmake, build

I am new to building to source files and compiling C++ code.

The process that I am familiar with so far.

```
cd source_folder
mkdir build
cd build
ccmake ..
```

Upon doing this on MacOS, I see configuration options and I generate some files. Then I am confused which command to run within the build binaries folder to create the executable programs.

Do I run cmake, make, make install, make package or a combination of them?

Please give me an explanation, or a good resource where I can learn more about this. In Windows, I noticed that the configure process creates solution files, which can be built using Visual Studio. On Mac that did not work out. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

`make` is a program that builds programs (and does other things) based on rules in makefiles.
`make install` invokes the `make` program to "build" the target named "install" (which can do anything at all, but usually installs something somewhere).
`cmake` is a program that generates makefiles (and other things) from "cmake files".
`ccmake` is an interactive terminal interface for `cmake`.

Exactly what commands you need to run depends on what's in those files.
If you wrote them, you should know.
If you didn't write them, read the documentation.
If there is no documentation, you need to decipher the files yourself, or find somebody else who has.